# jquery drag and pull down pull up

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi is there any plugin with jquery for this:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/vxvgH/3/show/light/]
```

This has been done by mootools. i want the same thing for my webpage, but with jquery. thanks

Comment: Why not use mootools then? Have you searched for a plugin? Or try to make it yourself?

Comment: i am already using jquery, so dont wanna use mootools. i have searched but could not find one.

Comment: Well you could do it by using jquery draggable, restrict it to the y-axis. Create a div with stuff that needs to be visible as soon as you drag that handle and make that div grow according to where the handle is. If that makes sense

Comment: also have you played with the built in html5 draggable? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/